# Elegant reduce function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to reduce an array of objects (config values in my case).
My array looks like this:

```
const settings = [
  {room: null, key: 'radioEnabled', value: true},
  {room: 24,   key: 'radioEnabled', value: false},
  {room: 24,   key: 'name',         value: 'Jack'},
  {room: 23,   key: 'name',         value: 'Mike'},
  {room: 23,   key: 'radioEnabled', value: false},
  {room: null, key: 'tvEnabled',    value: false},
];
```

This array is not ordered in any way.
If a room is set to `null`, this means it is a global setting. 
Global settings can be overwritten by local settings.

I am trying to write a function to get all settings for a room. 
For room 24 it should return:

```
[
  {room: 24,   key: 'radioEnabled', value: false},
  {room: 24,   key: 'name',         value: 'Jack'},
  {room: null, key: 'tvEnabled',    value: false},
]
```

The order in which the values are returned is not important to me. 
I have been able to achieve this in more than one way, but the solutions just don't seem that elegant/readable to me. Can anybody suggest a more elegant idea?

My solutions are below and on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/ce2t1vru/6/).

```js
const settings = [
  {room: null, key: 'radioEnabled', value: true},
  {room: 24,   key: 'radioEnabled', value: false},
  {room: 24,   key: 'name',         value: 'Jack'},
  {room: 23,   key: 'name',         value: 'Mike'},
  {room: 23,   key: 'radioEnabled', value: false},
  {room: null, key: 'tvEnabled',    value: false},
];

const getAll_1 = function(room){
 return settings.reduce( (a, b) => {
   // remove all other rooms
   if(b.room && b.room!== room){
     return a;
   }

  // see if the setting is already added
   let found = a.find( (setting) => {
     return setting.key === b.key;
   })

  // we already have a local value in our return array, don't add/replace anything
   if( found && found.room === room) {
     return a;
   } 
  
   // we have a value, but it's not local. Replace the current value with the new one
   if( found ) {
      const index = a.findIndex( (setting) => {
      return setting.key === b.key;
    })
     a[index] = b;
     return a;
   }
  
   // we don't have this setting at all. add it. 
   return a.concat(b);
 }, []);
}

const getAll_2 = function(room){
 return settings
    // first filter out all other room settings, only keep current room and global values
   .filter( (setting) => {
    return setting.room === null || setting.room === room;
  })
    // than sort em so all local (high prio) values are up top
  .sort( (a, b) => {
    return (a.room > b.room) ? -1 : ( a.room < b.room ) ? 1 : 0;
  })
    // reduce the array, adding only global values if they are not already added as local value
  .reduce( (a, b) => {
    const found = a.find( (setting) => {
      return setting.key === b.key;
    })
    if (found){
     return a;
    }
    return a.concat(b);
  }, [])
}

console.log(`Stack Overflow does not support console.table. Open your console for better representation`);

console.log(`getAll_1 response:`);
console.table(getAll_1(24));
console.log(`getAll_2 response:`);
console.table(getAll_2(24));
```

```html
Check your console
```

Comment: Seems like `{room: 24, radioEnabled: true, tvEnabled: false}` would be a more useful data structure.

Comment: I don't understand your example! can you explain that why you select the record with `key = tvEnabled`?

Comment: @Pointy I think you meant `{name: 'Jack', radioEnabled: true, tvEnabled: false}`

Comment: TIL `console.table` is extremely useful

Comment: @pointy: that's out of my control.

Comment: @pooyan: if no room is set, it is a global value, that is to be applied to all rooms. 
The "tvEnabled" record is not overwritten by any local values, so the global value must be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first get the `specific` settings, and then add the `general` ones if there isn't already a specific one for the `key`:

```js
const settings = [
  {room: null, key: 'radioEnabled', value: true},
  {room: 24,   key: 'radioEnabled', value: false},
  {room: 24,   key: 'name',         value: 'Jack'},
  {room: 23,   key: 'name',         value: 'Mike'},
  {room: 23,   key: 'radioEnabled', value: false},
  {room: null, key: 'tvEnabled',    value: false},
];

const generalSettings = settings.filter(x => x.room === null);

const getSettings = (roomID) =>
{
    let keysAdded = new Set();

    // Get specific settings and add keys on the set.

    let res = settings.filter(x => x.room == roomID && keysAdded.add(x.key));
    
    // Add general settings.

    return generalSettings.reduce(
        (acc, curr) => keysAdded.has(curr.key) ? acc : [...acc, curr],
        res
    );
}


console.log(getSettings(23));
console.log(getSettings(24));
```

Comment: I liked the unedited version better (before the keysAdded)

Comment: @JasperZelf This has a performance improvement, however, you are welcome to use the one you like.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, which might or might not help with your fundamental requirements, is to convert this to a more useful format:

```js
const roomSettings = settings => {
  const globals = settings.filter(s => s.room == null)
    .reduce((all, {key, value}) => ({...all, [key]: value}), {})
  
  return settings.filter(s => s.room != null)
    .reduce((all, {room, key, value}) => ({
      ...all, 
      [room]: {...(all[room] || globals), [key]: value}
    }), {} )
}

const settings = [{"key": "radioEnabled", "room": null, "value": true}, {"key": "radioEnabled", "room": 24, "value": false}, {"key": "name", "room": 24, "value": "Jack"}, {"key": "name", "room": 23, "value": "Mike"}, {"key": "radioEnabled", "room": 23, "value": false}, {"key": "tvEnabled", "room": null, "value": false}, {"key": "name", "room": 25, "value": "Beth"}]

console.log(roomSettings(settings))
```

Note that this returns something like the following:

```
{
  23: {
    radioEnabled: false,
    tvEnabled: false,
    name: "Mike"
  },
  24: {
    radioEnabled: false,
    tvEnabled: false,
    name: "Jack"
  },
  25: {
    radioEnabled: true,
    tvEnabled: false,
    name: "Beth"
  } 
}
```

(I added 'Beth' to have at least one that wasn't `false`/`false`.)

This format looks more useful, but it certainly might not be for you.

Comment: This kind of question always yields surprising results. Of course there's a greater lesson but the OP and community have immense potential to bury it.

Answer (score 1):

basically it is easier to use filter over your array, this filter function wrapped in a higher function to receive the room number as a parameter.

edit: forgot about the reduce to remove the duplicates.

```js
const settings = [{
    room: 24,
    key: 'radioEnabled',
    value: false
  },
  {
    room: null,
    key: 'radioEnabled',
    value: true
  },
  {
    room: 24,
    key: 'name',
    value: 'Jack'
  },
  {
    room: 23,
    key: 'name',
    value: 'Mike'
  },
  {
    room: 23,
    key: 'radioEnabled',
    value: false
  },
  {
    room: null,
    key: 'tvEnabled',
    value: false
  },
];


const getConfigs = (room = null, settings = []) => {
  return settings
    // filter all the options that match our criteria.
    .filter(setting => setting.room === room || setting.room === null)
    // using reduce we will remove the duplicated key entries.
    .reduce((accum, currentVal) => {
      // if the index is -1 it means it is not on the array, so we add it. 
      const index = accum.findIndex(accumSetting => accumSetting.key === currentVal.key)
      if (index === -1) {
        accum.push(currentVal);
      } else { // it means that we have the entry. replace if we have a local one.
        if(currentVal.room === room && accum[index].room === null){
          accum[index] = currentVal;
        }
        
      }
      return accum;
    }, [])
}

const result24 = getConfigs(24, settings);
const result23 = getConfigs(23, settings);

console.log(result24);
console.log(result23);
```

Comment: Just returned to my code writing: "const filtered = " when it dawned on me... just use filter. 
Thank you sir.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not overwrite global values with local ones. 
If I switch the first 2 setting objects, the result will have the global value and not the local one.

Comment: @JasperZelf I added the condition that you needed, it is just an `else` after the index condition.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible alternative -

```js
const globals =
  { radioEnabled: true
  , tvEnabled: false
  }

const settings =
  [ { room: 24, name: 'Jack' }
  , { room: 24, radioEnabled: false }
  , { room: 25, name: 'Mike' }
  , { room: 25, tvEnabled: true }
  ]

const assign = (o1, o2) =>
  ({ ...o1, ...o2 })

const getConfig = (room, settings = []) =>
  settings
    .filter (s => s.room === room)
    .reduce (assign, globals)

console .log
  ( getConfig (24, settings)
    // { radioEnabled: false
    // , tvEnabled: false
    // , room: 24
    // , name: 'Jack'
    // }

  , getConfig (25, settings)
    // { radioEnabled: true
    // , tvEnabled: true
    // , room: 25
    // , name: 'Mike'
    // }
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

- Filter first for where `room` is null
- Then filter for where `room` is the desired room number
- Concatenate both results in that order
- Add that to a `Map` to get only one entry per key
- Output as an array

The fact that the first two filter-results are concatenated in that order will ensure that `null` room entries get lower priority than non-null entries.

```js
function getAll(room){
    return [...new Map([...settings.filter(a => a.room === null), 
                        ...settings.filter(a => a.room === room)]
               .map(a => [a.key, a])).values()]
}

const settings = [{room: null, key: 'radioEnabled', value: true},{room: 24,   key: 'radioEnabled', value: false},{room: 24,   key: 'name', value: 'Jack'},{room: 23,   key: 'name',         value: 'Mike'},{room: 23,   key: 'radioEnabled', value: false},{room: null, key: 'tvEnabled', value: false}];

console.log(getAll(24));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one `reduce` loop if you store result in object based on `key` field and then get its values to return an array as a result.

- Check if room is `null` or target value
- Check if `key` property for that setting doesn't exist or if its room value is `null`

```js
const settings = [{"room":null,"key":"radioEnabled","value":true},{"room":24,"key":"radioEnabled","value":false},{"room":24,"key":"name","value":"Jack"},{"room":23,"key":"name","value":"Mike"},{"room":23,"key":"radioEnabled","value":false},{"room":null,"key":"tvEnabled","value":false}]

const getAll = room => {
  return Object.values(settings.reduce((r, e) => {
    if (e.room == null || e.room == room) {
      if (!r[e.key] || r[e.key].room == null) r[e.key] = e
    }
    return r;
  }, {}))
}

console.log(getAll(24))
```